# Subclass variables not inherited when building on iPhone

Tags: ios, inheritance, subclass

I'm new to Objective-c, so sorry if I'm missing something really obvious. I'm currently coding a game that incorporates lots of mini games. I've built a

SuperGameController

subclass of UIViewController, and then have all my games as subclasses of this. The SuperGame Controller has a number of variables defined in the interface as follows,

```
@interface SuperGameController : UIViewController {
    MainViewContoller *mainView;

    bool GAME_PLAYING;
    bool PAUSED;
    bool WIN;

    ball *theBall;
    UIImage *mainBall;
    UIImageView *ballView;
}
```

and as such, (I'm told) I don't need to define these variables in the header file of each individual game. I've built a few of these mini games and they work on the iPhone 4.3 Simulator, but when I try to Run the project on my iPhone, it tells me that each of these variables is

```
undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Is there something I need to do to make sure the project runs on the iPhone or am I just missing something obvious here? I've played around a lot and haven't found anything that helps. Any help you could give would be amazing!!

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you using any `@synthesize` properties without explicit variables?

Comment: Also, are you getting any other errors/warnings?

Comment: I have one @synthesize property in the super class, and this is declared in every subclass too, but has not beed assigned in any place yet. Do I need to explicitly used it?

Comment: and no, this is the only error I get...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an XCode bug - it compiles it fine for the simulator, but not for the device.

Use self->[name] as a workaround (e.g. self->theBall, self->GAME_PLAYING, etc.)

Edit: to clarify, that is assuming you don't use properties but the ivars directly. If you make properties out of theBall, GAME_PLAYING, etc., use self.[property] (i.e. dot, not the ->).